# Get e-mail notifications for questions tagged with two specific tags, or one tag but not another tag

Tags: support, tags, stackexchange.com, email-notification

There is a tag which is used in two different contexts, and for one of them, I should be able to provide answers. It is pretty easy to detect which context is being used either by checking if one other tag is also set, or by checking if a third tag is not set.

Now, I'd like to get e-mail notifications for these questions. I can subscribe to filters on the Stackexchange site, but these filters don't seem to support complex queries.

So, in short: **How can I get e-mail notifications for all new questions tagged with two selected tags, or with one tag but not another tag?**

Comment: No such option exists. You can subscribe to RSS feed of two tags, for example [RSS feed of questions tagged both C# and JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/c%23+javascript).

Answer (score 2):

1. Sign up for [If This Then That](http://ifttt.com).
2. Get the RSS feed for the two tags for which you want notifications.
3. Then, use a recipe to have new items in an RSS feed sent via email. Here is [one such recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/103260), or you can roll your own.

Now, whenever a new item is posted with both tags, you'll receive an email message with the question.

You can do this for any RSS feed, of course, so you can do it for combinations of three, four or five tags as well. Anything you can search for, really, so you can do negation (`[c#] -[javascript]`).